# Invalid Token Error Auth0 React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, auth0

After trying to follow this setup for react native with Auth0 https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/00-login, I was referred to another setup involving Expo because React Native now uses expo. The link to that setup is here https://github.com/expo/auth0-example. After trying to incorporate this example with my project I keep getting an "Invalid Token" warning and a "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection" warning.

Here is the code that I closely adapted from the sample:

```
import Expo, { AuthSession } from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';
import jwtDecoder from 'jwt-decode';

const auth0ClientId = 'OX7ZOyOM9dPrOZlxCz28qsbg3jYFPYRL';
const auth0Domain = 'https://tinder-score.auth0.com';

/**
 * Converts an object to a query string.
 */
function toQueryString(params) {
  return '?' + Object.entries(params)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    .join('&');
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: undefined,
  };

  _loginWithAuth0 = async () => {
    const redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
    const result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
      authUrl: `${auth0Domain}/authorize` + toQueryString({
        client_id: auth0ClientId,
        response_type: 'token',
        scope: 'openid name',
        redirect_uri: redirectUrl,
      })
    });
    console.log(result);
    if (result.type === 'success') {
      this.handleParams(result.params);
    }
  }

  handleParams = (responseObj) => {
    if (responseObj.error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', responseObj.error_description
        || 'something went wrong while logging in');
      return;
    }
    console.log(responseObj);
    const encodedToken = responseObj.id_token;
    const decodedToken = jwtDecoder(encodedToken);
    const username = decodedToken.name;
    this.setState({ username });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.username !== undefined ?
          <Text style={styles.title}>Hi {this.state.username}!</Text> :
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Example: Auth0 login</Text>
            <Button title="Login with Auth0" onPress={this._loginWithAuth0} />
          </View>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 40,
  },
});

Expo.registerRootComponent(App);
```

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. Have you been able to resolve this issue? It's scary that it's been more than a year since this question was posted and it's received no response whatsoever!

Comment: I haven't I would try someone else